# Allow only postgres user list roles

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

How to forbid non superusers to see other users in postgresql server?

ex. If currently logged in user is not a superuser then the result from

> SELECT * from pg_roles;

or

> \du

should be only rows with his role

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can revoke access to the authentication IDs table in the system catalogs:

```
REVOKE SELECT ON pg_catalog.pg_authid FROM public;
REVOKE SELECT ON pg_catalog.pg_auth_members FROM public;
```

Note that revoking access to `pg_roles` is not sufficient, as `pg_roles` is just a view over `pg_authid` and it's trivial to run the view query manually or define a new view with the same query. The `information_schema` views also use `pg_authid` directly and are unaffected by revoking access to `pg_roles`. It is not necessary to revoke access to `pg_roles` if you've revoked access to `pg_authid`.

Be aware that revoking access to global tables is still a per-database operation.

Revoking access to system catalogs may have side effects, including:

- Some system functions not working as expected
- Some metadata operations in tools like the JDBC driver failing
- ... etc

and is not generally considered supported.

Answer (score 0):

```
revoke select on pg_roles from public;
```

Comment: @KrzysztofMiksa how did it not work?  I tried it on an instance of Pg 9.0 and it seemed to work fine: allowed log in from an ordinary user, normal permitted operations by that user on objects it had grants for, but permission denied for that user on `\du` or `select ... from pg_roles`

Comment: @dbenhur It won't stop access to `information_schema` or queries that work against `pg_authid` directly. See my answer.

Comment: @CraigRinger yeah, I limited my answer to the OPs specific example use case, and expected pg_roles was merely a view that could be bypassed but lamely didn't dig deeper in by flyby answer earlier. Thanks for your more thorough answer.