# Postgresql database objects security

Tags: security, postgresql

I am developing an application which will use a postgreSQL database backend. I want to prevent the user from seeing some of the db objects - stored procs implementation in particular etc.

The "obvious" (but perhaps wrong) way is to GRANT CRUD access to the database to a specific user who will have an encrypted uname/pwd?

Is there another way of doing this?.

Note: My target audience are largely non-programmers, so I don't need anything that is "unbreakable" (assuming such a thing existed).

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL, how can i restrict access to code in a function for a user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651720/postgresql-how-can-i-restrict-access-to-code-in-a-function-for-a-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't really support limiting visibility of procedure source code, user or database lists, etc. The best thing to do is accept that, or implement the procedure in C or PL/Java where it's somewhat harder to examine at the cost of considerably greater complexity of implementation.

In general, you should not have the database/table owner be the day-to-day operational user of the DB. Create a new user and `GRANT` it only the rights that it needs.

Most of the system catalogs have default `SELECT` rights granted to `public` so you really want to limit access you would need to explicitly `REVOKE` that access then `GRANT` it back to the database owner and any other users that should have it. You're likely to want to limit access to `pg_proc` if you want to limit access to procedure sources, for example. Such an approach is limited and fragile (root can always gain PostgreSQL superuser access, and from there do anything), but you've said that's probably OK for your purposes.

Messing with the system catalogs isn't really supported and can cause issues with metadata access in JDBC, psql, etc. See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13003392/398670). If you mess with the catalogs and something breaks, you get to keep the pieces.

BTW, if you modify the catalogs, please try to avoid asking questions about databases with hand-modified catalogs here. At minimum specify *extremely* clearly that you have messed with the system catalogs and *exactly* what you have done. If possible, reproduce the issue on an unmodified database first.

Comment: I can live with the risks you mentioned, so thats fine. Could you please include the `REVOKE` commands I need to type, I am not familiar with the system catalogue. Ideally, I would also want to prevent anyone from seeing the available users for that database.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli See the related answer I linked to above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999274/allow-only-postgres-user-list-roles).

Comment: I don't recall exactly, but I thought revoking anything from pg_proc results in FKs breaking and other things. Basically Postgre doesn't support hiding the object implementation like Oralce, SQL Server, and Enterprise DB do.  Maybe write your proc in Java or C and maybe there you can use a obfuscator that can be executed against the Java or C code before you compile it to help hide what it's doing.

Comment: @JustBob That's possible; I'd certainly advise testing. You could always revoke access to `pg_proc.prosrc` - or, rather, revoke access to `pg_proc` then grant it to all columns except `pg_proc.prosrc`. Implementing procs in C is a better option for sure, but is a lot more work.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I did look at the code at the link you included in your answer - however, the REVOKE was being made on specific columns of the pg_catalog DBO. It is not clear from the example in the link, which fields on the pg_catalog DBO I need to REVOKE rights from.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli `pg_catalog` is a schema, not a table. `pg_proc` is a table in `pg_catalog`, with the fully qualified name `pg_catalog.pg_proc`. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html . I do *NOT* recommend that you mess with the system catalogs if you aren't familiar with schemas, the privelege model, granting and revoking privs, etc. Just accept that your customers can see your procedure source code. I will not give you a copy-and-paste recipe, you need to *understand* what you are doing if you mess with the catalogs.

Comment: @CraigRinger: ok, thanks. messing with the catalogue seems too fragile. I'll simply implement the code I want 'hidden' in a shared library.